# Pagination doesn't work for home page custom post type query

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I've spent hours trying to figure this out, tried TONS of different methods and all failed in their own way.

What I'm trying to do:

Limit home page custom post types (woo_estate) to 6 and then paginate the rest.

What happens:

Not only the home page custom post types don't get limited, no pagination is added.

Current template code that loads in home page:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/oVYI4D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a double query and that was why nothing worked.

```
var_dump($wp_query);
```

helped me find out about this fact.

A lot of the codes I used should have worked in the first place.

Once the double query was removed, everything worked again.

Comment: Cool, at least something I suggested worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I did something like this recently, but this is how I did it:

```
 $showNum = 10;
 $startNum = 0;

 if($paged > 0){
    $pageNum = $paged - 1;
    $startNum = $pageNum * $showNum;
 } elseif($paged == 0){
    $paged = 1;
 }
```

Then I went ahead and used the modified $paged value to request entries within the range of the requested page.

In the code sample you provided, you are defining $paged on line two. If this is a template file, then the $paged variable should already be defined by the time it gets to this page.

If I'm understanding it right, the $paged variable is used for determining what page of the set you are on. Do a `var_dump($wp_query);` to figure out what the current value of $paged is on your system.

Maybe this will help.

Comment: It's the home page, I have no idea how to define it by the time it gets to this page as most users just navigate directly to this page by entering the website address.

Furthermore, I replaced my own $paged variable at top with the one you gave and I didn't see any changes.
Surely I'm doing something wrong but my newbie knowledge limits my understanding of where and how.

Comment: this is the website address by the way: http://www.daycagayrimenkul.com/

Comment: var_dump($wp_query); contents:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/H4heWm

Comment: Are you passing `posts_per_page = -1` to the function?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a custom WP_Query and WP_PageNavi, this is what will solve the pagination issue:

```
if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')){
   wp_pagenavi(array(
        'query' =>$my_query
    ));
}
```

Check it an confirm if this works!

Comment: Did that but nothing changed, the page still shows all the posts although I want 6 to be shown but there's no errors either. No navigation still.

See it in action: http://www.daycagayrimenkul.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ano paste this code in your function.php and this might help you

```
function change_custom_posts_per_page($query)
{
    if( !empty( $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) ) {
        switch ( $query->query_vars['post_type'] )
        {
            case 'woo_estate':  // Post Type name
                $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 6;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return $query;
}

if( !is_admin() )
{
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_custom_posts_per_page' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already fixed the issue, turns out I had a double query coming from the parent template file and removing it solved everything.